# Use derivatives of two functions to make statements about their respective rates of growth?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

In general, whether $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$, or $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \infty$, or $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = C$,

would the same be true using any degree derivatives to compute those limits?

For ex, **if** $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$, **then** $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = 0$, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f''(x)}{g''(x)} = 0$, etc...

It kind of makes sense intuitively at least for the first derivative since we're really analyzing rates of growth; but even though I suspect it might be true as well for higher degrees of derivatives, it's less intuitive to me.

**Also, how would you prove it**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is not true.

> For ex, **if** $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$, **then** $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = 0$, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f''(x)}{g''(x)} = 0$, etc...

For a counterexample, consider

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}=0.$$

But

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\cos x}{1}\ne0.$$

Perhaps if we limit $f,g$ to polynomials, your claim should be valid.  So in case you mean that, then it suffices to prove that $g$ must have degree greater than $f$, yes?

Comment: Thank you for the counterexample. It made some kind of intuitive sense to me, but I guess that's why it's important to prove (or disprove) things formally.